# Vuetify elements do not appear perfectly on netlify after deployment

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, netlify

My team and I developed a website using VueJS. In one of the pages, we used Vuetify elements such as [vue-extension-panels](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels) and [v-card](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards#cards). During development, we run using npm run dev and everything looks fine. I believe that all dependencies are installed correctly as it appeared fine during development.

Then, we deployed the web with [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/). After deployment, Vuetify elements do not seem to appear correctly.

Below are the images that compare before and after deployment on Netlify:

[image: Accordion before deployment]

[image: Accordion after deployment]

Here is the packages.json:
[image]

So, it would be great if someone can explain why it is not showing properly or if someone knows netlify compatibility with Vuetify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use any library with netlify. When you use `$ vue add vuetify` to add the dependency, everything should be fine. If you did install it otherwise, make sure to check the following things.

Vuetify is under `dependencies` in your **package.json**.

```
"dependencies": {
  "core-js": "^3.4.3",
  "vue": "^2.6.10",
  "vuetify": "^2.1.0"
}
```

You correclty include it in your **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

vuetify plugin (`src/plugins/vuetify.js`)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({});
```

You have a **vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But my team and I were using Nuxt.js to develop the website.